# How can i persist a List of Custom class as a Json in hibernate using UserType?

Tags: java, json, spring, oracle, hibernate

How can i persist a List of Custom class as a Json in hibernate using UserType ?

What i am trying to achieve is my class is to store this list of custom class Condition into database as JSON.

```
@Entity
public class PortfolioRule  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PORTFOLIO_RULE_ID")
    private int portfolioRuleId;

    @Column(name = "RULES_JSON")
    private List<Condition> conditions;
```

like

> [{ "rule": 10 }, { "rule": 20}]

Since Condition is a an Abstract class which can be implemented in EqualTo or LessThan.
I am ready to store a field CLASS to the serialized JSON as below:

> [{ "rule": 10 , "CLASS": "com.my.company.EqualTo"}, { "rule": 20, ,
>   "CLASS": "com.my.company.LessThan"}]

i want a UserType implementation which serializes from list of conditions into JSON and deserialzes from JSON (Stored as CLOB) in database to  list of conditions again.

Comment: *UserType* interface is well documented, do you have trouble wth some of it`s methods or you not know how to (de) serialize to/from JSON?

Comment: Correct i need help on how to implement my userType implemntation class

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765893/storing-a-listsomeclass-as-json-in-a-text-field-with-hibernate/32890111#32890111