# Store a set<String>/ list<customType> as JSON datatype [Mysql 5.7] [Hibernate 5.1.0.Fina]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following Java Entity

```
public class EntityDefinition extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vertical_definition_id")
    private AnalyticalVertical analyticalVertical;

    @Column(name = "entity_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String entityName;

    @Column(name = "predicate", nullable = false)
    private List<RawPredicate> predicate;

    @Column(name = "inclusion_fsn_set")
    private Set<String> inclusionFsnSet;

    @Column(name = "exclusion_fsn_set")
    private Set<String> exclusionFsnSet;
}
```

I want to store predicate, inclusionSet and exclusionSet as JSON type in Mysql.

I have checked the following answers:
[Storing a List<SomeClass> as JSON in a text field with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765893/storing-a-listsomeclass-as-json-in-a-text-field-with-hibernate)
[Store/Retrieve Json data to/from Mysql 5.7 database using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819485/store-retrieve-json-data-to-from-mysql-5-7-database-using-hibernate)

Has anyone ever solved this in a production code and share the solution?

Regards

Edit : I am currently combining the approaches as mentioned in the above links. If I am able to get a working code then will share it here.