# how can I use spring to deserialize a postgres jsonb column to a list of objects?

Tags: hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of domain objects being saved to a postgres jsonb column (hibernate/jackson). The save works as expected but I get a mapping exception when deserializing. It looks like jackson is trying to deserialize to the domain object rather than a list of domain objects as specified by the type.

This is the field. It gets serialized and saved properly, as a list of stores.

```
@TypeDef(name = "stores",
    typeClass = JSONBUserType.class,
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = JSONBUserType.CLASS,
            value = "com.project.domain.metadata.Store")
    }
)


    @Column(name = "stores")
    @Type(type = "stores")
    private List<Store> stores;
```

This is the error I get when fetching the saved info. It looks like jackson is trying to deserialize it into a Store object rather than `List<Store>`.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.tgt.mkt.customdam.domain.metadata.Store out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [{"id": "T1230", "description": "store description"}]; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.tgt.mkt.customdam.domain.metadata.Store out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [{"id": "1230", "description": "store description"}]; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Here is a snippet of the request body that I sent to save the info with Postman. Is there a reason Jackson would be able to deserialize a list from a REST call but not from the DB?

```
"stores": [
        {
            "id": "T1230",
            "description": "store description"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: `Jackson` expects `JSON Object` but it sees `JSON Array`. You need to provide `List<com.project.domain.metadata.Store>` somehow. Check: [Storing a List<SomeClass> as JSON in a text field with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765893/storing-a-listsomeclass-as-json-in-a-text-field-with-hibernate) and [How to map JSON collections using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Yes it's expecting a JSON Object. My question is why. When I save the data it accepts the list of objects and saves correctly. When I fetch that same data with the same domain object with the same field that is a List of objects, jackson expects an object rather than a List of objects. Why does jackson deserialize correctly to a List of objects from the REST call but tries to deserialize to an Object when fetching from the DB? I'm using the same domain object with the same fields when deserializing from the REST call and from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution in a different project my team is working on. I'm not sure how or why but updating the @Parameter by prepending "[L" and adding a semicolon at the end of the classname fixed it.

```
@Parameter(name = JSONBUserType.CLASS,
            value = "[Lcom.tgt.mkt.customdam.domain.metadata.Store;")
```

and updating the field to a Store[].

```
    @Column(name = "stores")
    @Type(type = "stores")
    private Store[] stores;
```

Comment: Take a look on `JavaDoc` for [Class.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--), especially on `class or interface`     `Lclassname;` and: '[' characters representing the depth